# Animating, exporting from multiple angles

Tags: rendering, animation, keyframes

Is there a way that I can export a walking cycle of a character from many different angles?

Basically what I would like is to have 12 frames export from a characters walking cycle than have the character's base bone turn 45 degrees and than have the walking cycle export again.

The way I'm currently doing this is by coping the whole animation of a character 8 times. This is extremely difficult when a character animation is hundreds of the frames long and one single little change will force me to copy it all over again.

Is there perhaps something similar to the AE's " loopOut("cycle") ".

[image]

This character in the image has 12 frames per side and 16 sides. If you will notice ever 12 frames I rotate the base bone so that the character turns 22.5 degrees. This way I can export the whole character while I do other things. This saves me a lot of time. The problem is that now I'm working on characters that will have hundreds of frames and 8-32 sides. I need a better way to do this. Is there any way to make an animation loop?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to rotate the camera instead? That way you don't have to copy the character's animation, only make it loop a few more times. You could also set up four different cameras from the correct four different angles. Also look into http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.pt/2013/11/addon-batch-frame-rendering.html or https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/render/

Answer (score 1):

After some searching I have found the answer myself, and I would like to leave it here for others.

Under the F-curves select the animation and just add a Make Cyclic Modifier by pressing Shift+E. This works just like the loopOut() script in After Effects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you could just render your animation from the first angle, then move the camera to the second angle and render, and so on.

When you're done, you can combine these in the video sequence editor.

Comment: I know I can do it manually. But What I need is a way to stack up all the animations so that I can let them export when I go to sleep rather that waiting around for hours.